# Is a FULL OUTER JOIN neccessary for this situation?

Tags: sql-server, outer-join

I'm trying to find an alternative to using a FULL OUTER JOIN for a stored procedure I am writing. Here's the scenario.

Two tables of mostly unrelated data representing events that need to occur. The events need to be processed in chronological order and both tables have a datetime column. So I need to get a single table that acts as a list of ALL these events ordered by datetime (those two datetime columns need to be mixed together).

A small catch: sometimes events from the two tables will be related, and in this case, event from Table A needs to go first regardless of the datetime. So if A has 3 events, and B has 3 events, but there is a single related pair between A and B, I want to return 5 rows. In cases where there is unrelated data, there will be NULL data (and that's ok, I use NULL data checks to determine what to do next, i.e. process event A or B, etc.)

Currently what I have looks something like this:

```
    SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN A.EventDateTime IS NULL THEN B.EventDateTime
        ELSE A.EventDateTime 
    END AS SortDateTime,
    A.EventId,
    B.EventId,
    FROM A FULL OUTER JOIN B
    ON A.RelatedData=B.RelatedData
    ORDER BY SortDateTime
```

Comment: Do you mean by `event from Table A needs to go first regardless of the datetime` that you insert the B event after the A event, or not at all? And could you give us some test data, something like 3 events in A, 3 events in B, and the results you need?

Answer (score 5):

That should be fine

also instead of using CASE

```
 CASE
        WHEN A.EventDateTime IS NULL THEN B.EventDateTime
        ELSE A.EventDateTime 
    END AS SortDateTime,
```

you can do this

```
COALESCE(A.EventDateTime,B.EventDateTime) AS SortDateTime,
```

Which is a little shorter

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to avoid the OUTER JOIN you might try

```
SELECT A.EventDateTime, A.EventID
FROM A
UNION ALL
SELECT B.EventDateTime, B.EventID
FROM B WHERE B.RelatedData NOT IN (SELECT RelatedData FROM A)
```

The above `NOT IN` in can be written as `NOT EXISTS SELECT 1 FROM A WHERE A.RelatedData = B.RelatedData` or as `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` if your RDBMS has preferences (or if correlated sub-query is better for your dataset).

Answer (score 0):

If there is no exact relation between the two, I can't think of any other way you could perform this.